# Using slightly different architecture between pretraining and fine-tuning

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

Apologies beforehand, if my following description is not comprehensive enough.
Suppose I have trained a simple Resnet like model with the following structure for the basic blocks :

```py
self.layer1 = self._make_layer(self.inplanes, outplanes[0], num_blocks = 3, stride=1)
self.layer2 = self._make_layer(self.inplanes, outplanes[1], num_blocks = 3, stride=2)
self.layer3 = self._make_layer(self.inplanes, outplanes[2], num_blocks = 3, stride=2)
self.layer4 = self._make_layer(inplanes = outplanes[2],  planes=outplanes[3], num_blocks = 3, stride=2)
```

Now I want to fine-tune from this model. But instead of repeating the same shaped blocks 3 times, I want to condense them into a single layer and load into my fine-tuning model :

```py
self.layer1 = self._make_layer(self.inplanes, outplanes[0], num_blocks = 1, stride=1)
self.layer2 = self._make_layer(self.inplanes, outplanes[1], num_blocks = 1, stride=2)
self.layer3 = self._make_layer(self.inplanes, outplanes[2], num_blocks = 1, stride=2)
self.layer4 = self._make_layer(inplanes = outplanes[2],  planes=outplanes[3], num_blocks = 1, stride=2)
```

So essentially, it's the same model, but I am reducing the number of repeatation by condensing the learned weights into a single one. To be noted that the repeated blocks all have the same shape.

Is there any way to implement this or it's simply not mathematically or theoretically correct? I think it's somewhat similar to knowledge distillation - conceptually?

In fact, I was thinking whether I could also modify the kernel size similarly.

Comment: Are you asking what the impact is of reducing the number of residual blocks from 3 to 1? If not, can you state your actual question more clearly?

Comment: What do you mean by condense - you may be able to copy say just the first n trained layers into a new model and fine tune that. What you seem to be suggesting is to remove alternative layers (i.e. blocks) and I very much doubt that would work well.

Comment: I am particularly curious about whether there is any literature or implementations, that explore how we can combine the learned weights of, for example, the three (num_blocks) consecutive layers in the network to a single layer of the same dimension - through some information distillation or mapping techniques? 
Again, apologies if this sounds dumb.